# Putting values into matrix

Tags: c, matrix

After declaring a matrix matrix[2][2] with a global scope, I wanted to put values into it, in a more readable form.

```
  int matrix[line][col];

  int function() {

  matrix[0][0] = 1;
  matrix[1][0] = 2;
  ...
 }
```

But the above is not very readable. I saw that is also possible to use:

```
  int matrix[line][col] = {
   {1,2},
   {3,4},
   ...
   }
```

which I think is more readable. But after declaring a matrix with global scope I can't put values (like above) inside it in a function.

```
      int matrix[line][col] \\ global scope with some number of lines and columns

      void function() {  \\ some function

      matrix = {
      {1,2},
      {3,4},
      ....
    }
```

The way of putting values inside the matrix like above doesn't work.

Comment: I think you are confusing assignment with initialization.

Comment: Yes, one can't do that. What's your question?

Comment: If you want extremely readable code, don't code C.

Comment: How should I put the values into the matrix correclty? In the "more readble way"

Comment: You can initialize a matrix at global scope by using an initializer `= { …values…};` where the matrix is defined.  Ditto for a fixed-size array at block scope (inside a function).  You can't define a global matrix with variable size; you can't initialize a local matrix with variable size.  In C, you cannot assign to a matrix.

Comment: Your matrix is an array. You cannot assign an array, C doesn't allow it. If you need ro assign literal values to matrices, you may want to try making your matrix a `struct`, but why would you need that?

Comment: Having variables with a global scope is dangerous and not recommended anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is simply not possible. Using the form `int matrix[line][col] = { {1,2}, {3,4}, ... }` is only allowed during initialization.

You could do something like this:

```
int function() {
  int row0[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 ... };
  memcpy(matrix[0], row0, sizeof(row0));
  int row1[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 ... };
  memcpy(matrix[1], row1, sizeof(row0));
}
```

If that's better or not is up to you. Unfortunately, these things will always be a bit clumsy in C.

Comment: memcpy row by row? Why not nemcpy the entire matrix?